# Newton's First Law of Motion (Vectors)

Tags: vectors

A swing chair of mass 8kg is suspended by two taut ropes as shown in the diagram, the tension forces in ropes 1 and 2 are $T\underline1$ and $T\underline2$ respectively.

**Diagram**  : [image: Vectors Question]

**Question**  : By resolving vectors into $\underline i$ and $\underline j$ components find the exact magnitudes of $T\underline1$ and $T\underline2$

**My Working :**  
 
 $T\underline1$ Vertical = |$T\underline1$|$\cos60$ 
$T\underline1$ Horizontal = |$T\underline1$|$\sin60$ 
 
$T\underline2$ = |$T\underline2$|$\cos30$ 
$T\underline2$ = |$T\underline2$|$\sin30$

$\underline W$ = 8 $\times$ 9.8 
$\underline W$ = 78.4 N

Since the chair is in equilibrium, the Resultant Force must = 0.

I'm stuck here, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just one step away from the solution. 
Using $T_{i, x}$ and $ T_{i, y}$ for the horizontal and vertical component (maybe a further check at the angles could also help) respectively of the tension $T_i$, equilibrium of forces requires
$$ T_{1, x} + T_{2, x} = 0 $$ 
$$ T_{1, y} + T_{2, y} + W = 0$$ expressing zero resultant in the horizontal and vertical direction (along which the weight acts). 
Two equations, two unknowns $T_1$ and $T_2$ (as you have already expressed the components as a function of the tension), and you are there.

Comment: The exact values of the cos and sin which both had the denominator of 2 which made things easy. Thanks for the help!